# Firebase image retrieval

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I halfway know what's wrong with my code, but I can't find the exact place where there's an error. I'm trying to upload images to my database and storage, then retrieve the image by the url that's stored in the realtime database, but whenever I upload the image, it doesn't get stored in my realtime database, it's just stored in storage, so the retrieval code doesn't work. An image I currently have stored is called "landscape".

JavaScript code:

````
// variables
            var imgName, ImgUrl;
            var files = [];
            var reader = new FileReader();

// select image

            document.getElementById("select").onclick = function(e){
                var input = document.createElement('input');
                input.type= 'file';
                input.click();

                input.onchange = e => {
                    files = e.target.files;
                    reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function(){
                        document.getElementById("myimg").src = reader.result;

                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
                }
                input.click();
            }

// upload image
            document.getElementById('upload').onclick = function(){
                ImgName = document.getElementById('namebox').value;
                var uploadTask = firebase.storage().ref('Images/'+ImgName+".png").put(files[0]);

                uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
                    var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                    document.getElementById('UpProgress').innerHTML = 'Upload'+progress+'%';
                },
                function(error){
                    alert('error in saving image');

                },
                function(){
                    uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(url){
                        ImgUrl = url;
                    });
                    firebase.database().ref('Pictures/'+ImgName).set({
                        Name: ImgName,
                        Link: ImgUrl
                    });
                alert('image added successfully');
                }
                );
            }

// retrieve image

            document.getElementById('retrieve').onclick = function(){
                ImgName = document.getElementById('namebox').value;
                firebase.database().ref('Pictures/'+ImgName).on('value', function(snapshot){
                    document.getElementById('myimg').src = snapshot.val().Link;
                });
            }```

HTML code:
```        <style> img{ height: 200px; width: 200px; border: 2px solid black;}</style>

        Image Name <input id = "namebox" type="text"><br><br>
        <img id ="myimg"> <label id = "UpProgress"></label><br><br>

        <button id = "select">Select Image</button>
        <button id = "upload">Upload Image</button>
        <button id = "retrieve">Retrieve Image</button>```
````

Comment: just a tip: use `URL.createObjectURL(files[0])` instead of reading it as dataURL

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer, I just had to move one of the }); in the uploading functions and it worked